# need help on understanding Levenshtein distance

Tags: c#

I have just picked up programming and I am trying how does Levenshtein distance works.

I am comparing how similar is between 2 account names in a user database.

I am using the c# code from wiki, it gives a number that defines how many operations (insert/delete/replace) is needed for source string to end up as target string. However, instead of a number I want the percentage of match/mismatch of 2 strings.

How can i do it?

```
public static int DamerauLevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return target.Length;
        }
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target))
    {
        return source.Length;
    }

    var score = new int[source.Length + 2, target.Length + 2];

    var INF = source.Length + target.Length;
    score[0, 0] = INF;
    for (var i = 0; i <= source.Length; i++) { score[i + 1, 1] = i; score[i + 1, 0] = INF; }
    for (var j = 0; j <= target.Length; j++) { score[1, j + 1] = j; score[0, j + 1] = INF; }

    var sd = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var letter in (source + target))
    {
        if (!sd.ContainsKey(letter))
            sd.Add(letter, 0);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= source.Length; i++)
    {
        var DB = 0;
        for (var j = 1; j <= target.Length; j++)
        {
            var i1 = sd[target[j - 1]];
            var j1 = DB;

            if (source[i - 1] == target[j - 1])
            {
                score[i + 1, j + 1] = score[i, j];
                DB = j;
            }
            else
            {
                score[i + 1, j + 1] = Math.Min(score[i, j], Math.Min(score[i + 1, j], score[i, j + 1])) + 1;
            }

            score[i + 1, j + 1] = Math.Min(score[i + 1, j + 1], score[i1, j1] + (i - i1 - 1) + 1 + (j - j1 - 1));
        }

        sd[source[i - 1]] = i;
    }

    return score[source.Length + 1, target.Length + 1];
}
```

Comment: Define _match_ and _mismatch_ first.

Comment: Do you _understand_ the code you copied from Wikipedia? I think starting with _what_ the distance means and _how_ the algorithm works (both are pretty straightforward once you get them) is a better place to start than editing example code.

Comment: Isn't it just `(f_distance / f_originalStringLength) * 100f`?

Comment: Henk, what i mean is the percentage of how similar or difference source to the target, i know i get a number on the operation needed for the source to become the target, but how do i turn that into a "percentage of similarity"
Benjamin, no not really, except for what goes in the method and what is coming out, that is why i am asking around

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, yes i thought of it but which string should i use? I am comparing similarity of login account names, sorry should have mention that

Comment: @user904406 - that percentage is only obvious when you constrain it to strings of equal length. Otherwise you'll need a lengthy specification.

Answer (score 2):

The Levenshtein distance is (as Wikipedia will happily tell you) the smallest number of single-character changes (insert, modify or delete) required to change one string into another.  You can use it to determine how similar two strings are, since similar strings will have a low Levenshtein distance.

The maximum possible Levenshtein distance between two strings that have no similarity is the length of the longer of the two strings:

```
int maxLD = Math.Max(s1.Length, s2.Length);
```

Given that, you could potentially calculate a degree of similarity by calculating the actual distance:

```
int actualLD = LevenshteinDistance(s1, s3);
float LDratio = 1 - (float)actualLD / maxLD;
```

Strings that are identical will have `LDratio` equal to 1.  Very similar strings will have a high `LDratio` value, and very dissimilar strings will have an `LDratio` value approaching 0.

Multiply by 100 to get your percentage match.

Comment: Pretty much what I thought the OP meant.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I took a stab.  If he wants something different he'll let me know :)